# Hide and Show div in ajax call in external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.net MVC, and following is the Html code

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlAjax,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: dataValue,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#waitscreen").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#waitscreen").hide();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success")
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            alert("fail")
        }
    });


<div id=waitscreen>
  //some code
</div>
```

Code in external js

```
function _post(someparameter)
{
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlAjax,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dataValue,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#waitscreen").show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#waitscreen").hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success")
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                alert("fail")
            }
        });
}
```

Also tried adding document ready in above code it is still not working

Above code worked fine and it show and hide as expected, but now I need to repeat ajax call in every page so I decided to move in external  JS file now same code is not showing waitscreen.

Things I tried:

1. Loaded external script in head - Not working
2. Loaded external script at end of page - Not working

Question: I want to make hide and show work from external JS file

Comment: Any errors in the browser's dev console? Is jQuery included before the script on the other pages? Are you sure the external script is actually running? Do you see the alert from the success handler? And just to double check, all of your other html pages *do* have a div with that id?

Comment: Put your code inside $(document).ready(function(){ });

Comment: wrap your code inside `$(document).ready (function(){....});` and check

Comment: can you post your external JS here?

Comment: In external js, I already tried that too but then it shows function not found

Comment: Are you sure that your ajax is called at all? I mean do you get success or fail alert in page?

Comment: @SiamakFerdos yes it shows alert for success correctly, there is no problem with call

Comment: can you please put alert at top of extenal JS file and check is it added in page or not ?

Comment: yes alert is working, even the ajax call is working and going in success and error based on url values

Comment: @HarshalBulsara Is it working for you now ?? Your code is working for me as expected with hide and show div from external js.

Comment: @BasantaMatia No, it's not working, and I have tried on 2 different machines as well. I think it's something with asp.net MVC

Comment: are you trying to load this script in partial views ?

Comment: @SunilKumar No, but in future it can have a partial view

Comment: You can find the exact error by debugging on your browser. Firefox and Chrome have `Inspect` feature when you right click. Go to console to see the errors. Or put breakpoints in JS code and single step. I think I know the issue but I'll let you debug and figure it out yourself. You will learn it better.

Comment: @arvindpdmn, As I have already mentioned there is no error in console

Comment: Any error in Console of browser?

Comment: No errors in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet should help you. Tested by including the external JS file in the `<head>` of the main document and just below the inclusion of jQuery.

```js
// main window
var json = {"key": "value"}
     console.log('before calling _post()');
    _post(json); // call external JS


// code in external JS say test.js
function _post(someparameter)
{
    console.log('external JS called!');
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'http://www.niketpathak.com',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: someparameter,
          async: true,  
          beforeSend: function () {
              $("#waitscreen").show();
          },
          complete: function () {
             // $("#waitscreen").hide();
          },
          success: function (data) {
              alert("success")
          },
          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
              //delaying the error callback
              setTimeout(function() {
                  $("#waitscreen").hide();
                  console.log('after completing the http-request');
              }, 500);
          }
        });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=waitscreen>
    Waitscreen....
</div>
```

Also, note that I have used `async: true` (which is also the default) since setting it to false is **deprecated** and not a good idea as it  blocks the UI.

Comment: I have included div and js files in layout which is inherited by other pages can thid be a reason this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

My ajax code in External.js file,

```
function _post() 
{
  var data = {
    Email: "a@a.com",
    Password:"1111"
    }
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/hello/",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#waitscreen").show();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $("#waitscreen").hide();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success")
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        alert("fail")
    }
});
```

}

In my HomeController, I have hello method like this,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult hello(LoginViewModel data)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And in my all the views I have the "waitscreen" div.
Now I just reference the External.js file to my _Layout page, I just drag and drop after jquery reference.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/External.js"></script>
```

Then in end of the same _Layout page, i just call the method like this,

```
<script>
   _post();
</script>
```

Everything working properly. 
Note: If you have only one parameter in your hello action method and suppose you have written like (int x) then in that case it will through 500 error. Because in your RouteConfig.js its mentioned that, by default the parameter name should be id. So you need to write int id.
Hope its help.

Comment: And in my all the views I have the "waitscreen" div.. do I need to put div on all pages can i just put in layout only?

Comment: You need to put that div in all the page that you want to show. Otherwise you can create a partial view then render it in all the pages. BDW which error you are getting ? This code is working completely fine.

Comment: I think you just created the waitscreen div and nothing is there. Write some text inside the div, like Waiting... etc etc and give a break point to your action method, then you can see in your web page, it will display then hide.

Comment: I do have content in div, even after adding to individual page still it's not displaying, no error either

Comment: Did you add _Layout page to your view ? If no, then add it. Did you reference the external js file in your Layout page after all the js reference ? In no then add that. And in bottom of Layout, you just need to call that function. That's it.